# WPF/MVVM: Dynamically add checkboxes to 2 ColumnGrid based on available Enums

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I'm currently build a gui for a logger. The logger class has a enum `Types` with a couple of values defining the different log message types.

Now I want to create a gui for this logger. Part of this gui is a 2 column grid where a checkbox for each log message type is available. It shall be used to filter the log. In order to reduce future coding effort, I would like to add a checkbox for each available type of log message dynamically. So when ever a new value is added to `Logger.Types` the gui adapts automatically.

My xaml of the checkboxes look something like this:

```
 <CheckBox Name="CheckBoxTypeInformation" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
           Content="{myControls:LocalizationMarkup 'LOGMSG_TYPE_INFORMATION'}" 
           Command="{Binding FilterTypeCommand}" CommandParameter="Information"
           IsChecked="{Binding Path=FilterType[0]}"/>
```

So there is quite some work to be done for each checkbox:

1. Insert the cb into the 2 column grid in some manner by defining the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row`. The logic of it is not the problem
2. Set the Content with a custom LocalizationMarkup
3. Bind a command with dynamic CommandParameter. Here I would like to pass the actual enum value. But I was not able to do so in xaml atm.
4. Bind the IsChecked Property to an index in an array holding the IsChecked Status of all checkboxes.

I'm not quite shure how to handle this. As I understood it correctly I somehow have to add an `ObservableCollection<>` of a new custom class which has properties for each of the 4 wanted tasks.

I hope somebody can point me into the right direction on how to implement something dynamic as described in a propper mvvm/wpf manner.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF binding Enum list (or similar) to list of checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310595/wpf-binding-enum-list-or-similar-to-list-of-checkboxes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would't use a grid for that, but simply a List.
Define a classe named LogLevelViewModel with two properties

```
    private string _logDetails;

    public string LogLevelDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return _logDetails;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_logDetails == value)
            {
                _logDetails = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(LogLevelDetails));
            }
        }
    }

    private LogLevel _logLevel;

    public LogLevel LogLevel
    {
        get
        {
            return _logLevel;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_logLevel == value)
            {
                _logLevel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(LogLevel));
            }
        }
    }
```

Then define on your view model a ObservableCollection LogLevelViewModels

On the constructor of the view model, you can populate it With:

```
foreach (LogLevel level in Enum.GetValues(typeof(LogLevel )))
{
    LogLevelViewModels.Add(level );
}
```

On the XAML make sure to define a DataTemplate for LogLevelViewModel and that's it.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I orignally planed to use a grid in order to save space on the screen. But think a wrappanel will to the job.